# Resume a script after reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

How can I resume a script after a shutdown/restart of Windows 7/8?

I want to do a silent uninstall of one piece of anti-virus software. A reboot is then required. Then I want to resume the script automatically after the reboot and do a  silent install of the new anti-virus software.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of wanting to do it this way? Sounds sketchy to me

Comment: I need to roll out new A/V to 100 machines. To uninstall the old requires a reboot after the silent uninstall. And then the new is to be installed. How would you do it?

Comment: I wouldn't. It was just the 'silent' part that made it sound suspicious. A lot of spyware performs similar tasks such as the one you inquired about.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\
```

Make a new entry and set its value as the name of the script to run on startup. Note: this is for 32-bit Windows 8. For 64-bit, use

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\
```

Source: http://www.briangirton.org/2013/03/windows-8-startup-registry-location/